# SQL Server login failed with new windows user account

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I am new to the Microsoft SQL Server world.

I installed SQL Server on my computer, I logged in with the server name dot (`.`) it was good. But later I changed my Windows user account to Administrator. Now the problem is that I cant login with `.` (dot) and `(local)` again, as my old user account was able to.

Kindly let me know how to fix this. I couldn't find the solutions for this online.

I am using it in my own pc its not in network.

Comment: the issue is the server name

Answer (score 0):

Open your Object Explorer. It is found in the View tab of the top bar, or by pressing F8.

In the Security folder of your database is a Logins folder.

The Logins folder holds all of the users who are authenticated for login on any given database. You need to add any user to this folder who you want to have access to your database.

In this logins section, you can create new users that use both Windows Authentication and SQL Server authentication (just a username and password on start of application)

You can add any Windows account from your computer that you want to use your database, or you could create a SQL Server account and login with that same account information anytime you want to access your database, no matter what Windows account you are on.

Comment: sir, object explorer is empty . becouse iam not logged in.

Comment: You need to login with your old account so that you can add the new user.